# How to remove the shortiest subpaths from path?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I've a string contains some directory structure.

```
dirs='Rootdir/ 
    Secondrootdir/
    Rootdir/Subdir/
    Secondrootdir/Anothersubdir/
    Secondrootdir/Thirdsubdir/
    Secondrootdir/Anothersubdir/Subsubdir/'
```

I want to filter it and get the following:

```
dirs='Rootdir/Subdir/ Secondrootdir/Thirdsubdir/ 
      Secondrootdir/Anothersubdir/Subsubdir/'
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps something like this:

```
dirs="Rootdir/ Secondrootdir/ Rootdir/Subdir/ Secondrootdir/Anothersubdir/ Secondrootdir/Thirdsubdir/ Secondrootdir/Anothersubdir/Subsubdir/"

echo $dirs \ 
    | tr ' ' '\n' \
    | sed -e 's#\([^/]\)$#\1/#' \
    | sort -r \
    | gawk '!index(prev,$0){print;} {prev=$0;}'
```

this produces

```
Secondrootdir/Thirdsubdir/
Secondrootdir/Anothersubdir/Subsubdir/
Rootdir/Subdir/
```

Here, `tr` first splits the space-separated input into individual lines. `sed` makes sure that each path ends with a slash. In combination with `sort -r`, this has the consequence that if path p is a subpath of path q, then q comes first in sorted output. Finally, `gawk` filters only those paths which are not subpaths of the previous one. Thanks to the particular sort order, this effectively selects only leaves of the directory structure...

Answer (score 1):

I propose an alternative, other than the good @ewcz one, and explicit version that doesn't call external executables and respect the format proposed in the original question:

```
dirs='Rootdir/ 
    Secondrootdir/
    Rootdir/Subdir/
    Secondrootdir/Anothersubdir/
    Secondrootdir/Thirdsubdir/
    Secondrootdir/Anothersubdir/Subsubdir/'
out=()
for d in ${dirs};do
  found=0
  for db in ${dirs};do
      # d is subpath of db
      [[ ( "${db}" == "${d}"* ) && (${#db} -gt ${#d})  ]] && found=1 && break
  done
  [[ $found == 0 ]] && out+=($d)
done

echo ${out[*]}
```

Answer (score 1):

First show the lines to remove.
You mant to remove every path where you will also have the same path followed by some folder. Something like removing a string ending with `path/` when `path/more/` is found.
I use `"${dirs// }"` repairing the first line that ends with a space. THe solution will fail for a dir with a space, but the input format is missing quotes too.

```
sed -n '/\/.*\// s# *\(.*/\)\([^/]*\)/$#\1#p' <<< "${dirs// }"  | sort -u
```

Now you can use process substitution telling `grep` to skip all lines fond in the "file" given by the above command.
You need different `grep` options: `F` will ignore special meanings, `x` will match complete lines only, `v` will inverse the `grep` and `f` will read the strings to match from a file.

```
grep -Fxvf <(
   sed -n '/\/.*\// s# *\(.*/\)\([^/]*\)/$#\1#p' <<< "${dirs// }"  | sort -u
   ) <<< "${dirs// }"
```